# How to generate a PDF with a given template, with dynamic data in Python or NodeJS to be deployed on AWS

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf, html-pdf

Looking for recommendation of a library in Python(first preference) or NodeJS that can generate a pdf file preferably from dynamic html template to be run in AWS. Requirement is to generate invoice pdf to be sent to customers.

Have come across below 2 Node libraries:

- PDFKit
- jsPDF

Here we might have to deal with numbers for X and Y.

Better approach would be something where we can simply use html/css to generate template with placeholders which can be replaced with dynamic data(coming from database query).
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This approach worked for me in Python using below libraries:

Jinja2 - for generating HTML with custom data

xhtml2pdf - for generating PDF from HTML

Consider within your PROJECT DIR, there is a template file(invoice.html) and python file(pdf_generator.py)

**pdf_generator.py**

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa 
import jinja2
templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
TEMPLATE_FILE = "invoice.html"
template = templateEnv.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILE)

# This data can come from database query
body = {
    "data":{
        "order_id": 123,
        "order_creation_date": "2020-01-01 14:14:52",
        "company_name": "Test Company",
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "state": "MH",
    }
}

# This renders template with dynamic data 
sourceHtml = template.render(json_data=body["data"]) 
outputFilename = "invoice.pdf"

# Utility function
def convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename):
    # open output file for writing (truncated binary)
    resultFile = open(outputFilename, "w+b")

    # convert HTML to PDF
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(
            src=sourceHtml,            # the HTML to convert
            dest=resultFile)           # file handle to receive result

    # close output file
    resultFile.close()

    # return True on success and False on errors
    print(pisaStatus.err, type(pisaStatus.err))
    return pisaStatus.err

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pisa.showLogging()
    convertHtmlToPdf(sourceHtml, outputFilename)
```

**invoice.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
Name: {{ json_data.company_name }} <br>
City/State: {{ json_data.city }}, {{ json_data.state }} <br>
Date: {{ json_data.order_creation_date }} <br>
Order ID: {{ json_data.order_id }} <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have any style and CSS too ?

Answer (score 4):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake
The above library allows flexibility when it comes to dynamic invoices in node.js